# oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException error in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: xml-parsing, oracle12c, websphere-8

I'm trying to connect Websphere 8.5.5 with oracle 12c DB and WAS throwing an error saying java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException. Initially we got xdbtype class was not found and we resolved this by adding xdb6.jar to WAS's lib directory. Now even after adding xmlparserv2.jar to WAS's lib directory we are facing the same issue and it looks like WAS is not recognizing the jar file we deployed in lib directory. We are not sure whether this is problem in loading the jar file or its a version mismatch issue since xmlparserv2.jar is not available in Oracle pages to download. Please guide me on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Try setting the xmlparserv2.jar and xdb6.jar as additional JDBC driver jars in the JDBC provider config.

Comment: Hi I tried this already. I included xdb6.jar and xmlparswrv2.jar to JDbc provider in was. But still the same results